# Exclude folder with awk not working properly

Tags: linux, shell, awk, ls

I've to make a folder contents list using `ls -alis` and using `awk` to filter the results.

I'm having some problems with `$11 != "." && $11 != ".."` . I don't want to display the folder `.` and the folder `..` but they are still here.

```
ls --color -alis /home/user/ | 
tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f11 |
awk '$1 !~"^/\./$" { print $1 }'
```

I've tried `$11 !~ "^/./$"` as well.

Comment: You could avoid the issue by using `-A` (uppercase) which includes dotfiles *except* `.` and `..`.

Answer (score 0):

[Parsing output of `ls` is not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as filenames can have white-spaces newlines etc and will break your piped commands.

For your requirement you can just use this `printf` with `xargs`:

```
printf "%s\0" * | xargs -0 ls --color -Alis
```

Comment: That normally excludes files beginning with dot, which was presumably the purpose of using `-a`, although some shells have differing options to include them.

Comment: Very good point, thanks @dave_thompson_085. I agree using `-A` would be better to meet OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't double quote the regex, and the anchor points (`^` and `$`) go inside the regex:

```
awk '$11 !~ /^\.\.?$/ { print }'
```

That doesn't match a line where field 11 contains one or two dots (only).

This deals with the problems with the `awk` script; it is, however, debatable whether you should be parsing the output of `ls` as it is can be ambiguous.